# Embed message gif not working | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

The bot sends a embed message, but only the text and not the gif. I have the gif in a separate .json file so there will be different gifs when someone uses the command. But for some reason it doesn't work. Maybe it's because of the .json file? I really don't know, please help me.
***My code:***

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const prefix = require('../config.json');
const patGif = require('../PATSGIFS.json');

module.exports = {
  name: "pat",
  description: "Pat someone UwU",
  aliases:["pat"],


execute: async (client, message, args) => {
    const gif = patGif[Math.floor(Math.random() * patGif.length)];

    if (!message.mentions.users.first())
    return message.reply("***please mention someone.***");
    
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#FF8DC4 ")
    .setTitle(`*Aww how cute, ${message.author.username} gave ${message.mentions.users.first().username} a pat!*`) 
    .setImage(gif);(String[patGif[gif]])
    message.channel.send({embed})
}}
```

***The code of the .json file:***

```
{
    "patgif": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/d0/1e/15d01e231310bb6dabb3af0ae40fc209.gif"
}
```

(I know, its only one gif yet.)

***The error i get in the console when both files are in one folder:***
PICTURE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rzXP.png | I can't copy it from the console, so here's a picture.

***Here's a picture of the message:***
PICTURE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKGG3.png

Help would be appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: Is the filename uppercase `PATSGIFS.json`?

Comment: Yes it is. Why?

Comment: Because it says it can't find `../PATSGIFS.json`. Could you also take a screenshot of your folders showing this JSON file?

Comment: Sure. I only have these two files in my command folder right now. https://i.postimg.cc/k5TSS44k/patsgifs.png

Comment: Then it's in the same folder as this file, so it should be `require('./PATSGIFS.json');`

Comment: It works now - Thank you. But there's still no gif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple errors. First, you need to fix the path, it's `require('../PATSGIFS.json')`.

Another error is that the JSON file contains an object, not an array. From your code, it seems you want to pick a random gif from an array, so it should be something like this instead:

```json
[
  "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/d0/1e/15d01e231310bb6dabb3af0ae40fc209.gif",
  "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/d0/1e/15d01e231310bb6dabb3af0ae40fc209.gif",
  "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/d0/1e/15d01e231310bb6dabb3af0ae40fc209.gif",
]
```

And you should send the embed as-is, not inside an object with an `embed` key:

```js
message.channel.send(embed)
```

The full code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const prefix = require('../config.json');
const patGif = require('./PATSGIFS.json');

module.exports = {
  name: 'pat',
  description: 'Pat someone UwU',
  aliases: ['pat'],
  execute: async (client, message, args) => {
    const gif = patGif[Math.floor(Math.random() * patGif.length)];

    if (!message.mentions.users.first())
      return message.reply('***please mention someone.***');

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FF8DC4')
      .setTitle(
        `*Aww how cute, ${message.author.username} gave ${
          message.mentions.users.first().username
        } a pat!*`,
      )
      .setImage(gif);

    message.channel.send(embed);
  },
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - but what do you mean with array? Do i have to paste 

[
  "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/d0/1e/15d01e231310bb6dabb3af0ae40fc209.gif",
  "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/d0/1e/15d01e231310bb6dabb3af0ae40fc209.gif",
  "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/15/d0/1e/15d01e231310bb6dabb3af0ae40fc209.gif",
]

into the JSON file? I'm new to coding and im a bit confused right now, sorry.

Comment: If you have different gifs (gif1, gif2, gif3, etc), then you can add the URLs of these inside the square brackets like `["gif1.gif", "gif2.gif", "gif3.gif"]` and `patGif[Math.floor(Math.random() * patGif.length)]` will select one of them randomly every time the pat command is called.